# Error while installing ZenTest gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

```
narendra@narendra-laptop:~/rails_project/sample_app$ sudo gem install ZenTest
[sudo] password for narendra: 
ERROR:  Error installing ZenTest:
    ZenTest requires RubyGems version ~> 1.8. Try 'gem update --system' to update RubyGems itself.
narendra@narendra-laptop:~/rails_project/sample_app$ gem update --system
Latest version currently installed. Aborting.
narendra@narendra-laptop:~/rails_project/sample_app$ gem --version
1.8.10
narendra@narendra-laptop:~/rails_project/sample_app$
```

Comment: narendra@narendra-laptop:~/rails_project/sample_app$ gem --version1.8.10

Answer (score 1):

Try `gem install ZenTest` without the sudo.